# como faço para mudar o nome ou mesmo fazer interações em uma div

Tags: javascript

como faço para mudar o texto de uma div eu já tentei do modo que eu sabia usando o:

```
 function clicou() {
   var toc = document.getElementById('f1')
   toc.innerText="clicou"
}
```

estou tentando mudar o texto da div de id f1:

```js
function clicou() {
  var toc = document.getElementById('f1')
  toc.innerText = "clicou"
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(112, 128, 144, 0.61);
  display: flex;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

div#f1 {
  background-color: rgb(8, 179, 156);
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0.2mm;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

div#f2 {
  background-color: rgb(8, 179, 156);
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  border-right: 3px inset rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-left: 3px inset rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0.2mm;
}

div#f3 {
  background-color: rgb(8, 179, 156);
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  border-right: 3px inset rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0.2mm;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

div#f4 {
  background-color: rgb(8, 179, 156);
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0.2mm;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" midia="all">
</head>

<body>
  <header id="had">
    <div id="f1"> era para mudar aqui </div>
    <div id="f2"> home </div>
    <div id="f3"> consfigurações </div>
    <div id="f4"> informções </div>
  </header>

  <section id="sec"> </section>
  <footer id="foo"> </footer>
  <script src="comandos.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tenta colocar `toc.innerHTML = "clicou"` para ver se vai.

Comment: Vc apenas declarou a função, mas, não a executou em momento algum!

Answer (score 1):

Cria um botão pra executar a ação:

```
<button onclick="clicou();">Clique aqui</button>
```

E não esquece de botar ; no final de cada linha do js:

```
function clicou() {
   var toc = document.getElementById('f1');
   toc.innerText="clicou";
}
```

Caso tu não queira botão pra executar a ação, só coloca no final do js a chamada da função:

```
clicou();
```